# How to position element dynamically?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, frontend

Would it be possible to pick an element from one flow and place it in a different flow and make it behave as a part of that flow?

```css
.carousal-arrows {
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-bullets {
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.carousel-bullets .carousel-bullet {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-inline: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousal-arrows">
  <button>&#5176;</button>
  <button>&#5171;</button>
</div>
<ul class="carousel-bullets">
  <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
  <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
  <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
  <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
</ul>
```

Using the above `scss` I placed the `carousal-bullets` class element between the arrow buttons.

[image]

I have to manually specify the width of the container to accommodate the `bullets div`, would it be possible to dynamically update the width such that when the bullets in the container increase the width of the container should adjust accordingly and bullets will not layover the arrows.

Need to follow the same `HTML` structure as mentioned above.

Comment: Well, definitely not with the same structure only in CSS.
Or with a bit of JS.

Comment: I can do it with JS but wondering if this could be done using just CSS.

Comment: You might find an hack with css grid and `fr`. Not sure how however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may this will help you.

```css
      .carousal-arrows {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            position:absolute;

        }

        .carousel-bullets {
            display: flex;
            pointer-events: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        .carousel-bullets .carousel-bullet {
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            background-color: #000;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-inline: 4px;
        }

        .box {
            display: inline-block;
            width: fit-content;
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
  <div class="box">

        <div class="carousal-arrows">
            <button class="left">&#5176;</button>
            <button class="right">&#5171;</button>
        </div>

        <ul class="carousel-bullets">
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
            <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: I want the `carousal-bullets` class element to be placed in between the arrows.

Comment: @user12551649
i just updated as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done if you just restructure the ul elements between the buttons and set the position as relative. However there is a limit to the number of `carousel-bullet` that can be fit inside the buttons due to the fixed width of `carousal-arrows`.

```css
.carousal-arrows {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-bullets {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.carousel-bullets .carousel-bullet {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousal-arrows">
  <button>&#5176;</button>
  <ul class="carousel-bullets">
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    <li class="carousel-bullet"></li>
    
    
  </ul>
  <button>&#5171;</button>
</div>
```